# How to generate script of a stored procedure based on modified date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have 50 stored procedures and in those I have modified only 3 today, I just want to generate scripts for those 3 modified stored procedures.

How can I achieve this according to modified date??? Anyone please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
   SELECT name , create_date, modify_date ,sm.definition FROM sys.procedures sp
   Inner join sys.sql_modules sm  ON sp.object_id = sm.object_id 
   WHERE CONVERT(DATE,sp.modify_date)    = CONVERT(DATE, '02/19/2013')
```

Comment: I would recommend using `sys.procedures` instead of `sys.objects`. That way, you don't need to specify any `type` or anything - you already get *only* procedures ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this - run in SSMS with "Results to Text" to preserve tabs etc.

```
SELECT      M.definition
FROM        sys.procedures P WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN  sys.sql_modules M WITH(NOLOCK)
ON          M.object_id = P.object_id
WHERE       P.modify_date >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) -- Modified since midnight today.
```

Comment: I would recommend using `sys.procedures` instead of `sys.objects`. That way, you don't need to specify any `o.type` or anything - you already get *only* procedures ...

Comment: @Will A why need sys.sql_modules in you query?

Comment: OP wanted scripts for the procedures modified today - sys.sql_modules provides the underlying text behind (some types of) objects.

Comment: Thanks, Also the above query i sworking fine., Keep it for your ref

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
select p.name
  ,stuff(m.definition,CHARINDEX('create',m.definition,0),6,'alter') as definition
from sys.procedures p
inner join sys.sql_modules m
on m.object_id = p.object_id
where modify_date >= cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

the resultset is like

```
name          definition
sp_xxxxxx     alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_xxxxxx] ...
```

Comment: SELECT name , create_date, modify_date ,sm.definition FROM sys.procedures sp
   Inner join sys.sql_modules sm  ON sp.object_id = sm.object_id 
   WHERE CONVERT(DATE,sp.modify_date)    = CONVERT(DATE, '02/19/2013')